# mysql connection automatically closes on console closed

Tags: mysql

i am running mysql server 5.5 i haven't installed it as a service.
I am starting mysql from command line by typing mysqld.
Mysql is successfully started i can query anything now, But if i close this commandline window the mysql connection is also closed.

Why is this so ?

I want it run mysql even after the console is closed without installing it as a service. Is it possible to do so or i have to keep that console window open to do all the task.
How can i solve this problem.
Please help.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: operating system is windows 8.1

Comment: Generally you install it as a service as the Windows shell likes to close out all associated processes.

Comment: so why mysqld does not start the mysql service but net start mysql does

Comment: You're confusing the process `mysqld` with the method for starting it and keeping it running in the background. System services need to be launched a special way to keep them unattached to the window that started them, otherwise the behaviour is to close them out when you close that window.

Comment: you mean mysqld and mysql service are two different things

Comment: The service starts `mysqld`, and restarts it if that process crashes. It's a supervisory layer that you're missing if you call `mysqld` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a linux distro (e.g. ubuntu), then start it in a different shell (e.g. CTRL-ALT-F2) and move back to the shell you were already using.

If you are running from Windows, then why not start the GUI version of MYSQL server instead ?

In newer version of windows the (emulated) cmd is sandboxed which means that everything is discarded after closing the window, unless of course it is a service which will be hand by Windows.

Comment: so you mean i should use it as a service to use it even after closing the console. I tried installing it as a service but mysqld is not able to start the service however net start mysql does so. why ?

Comment: because net start mysql does not start your mysqld executable, but actually starts the mysql service

Comment: @avk It does start it, just does it in a round-about way.